# My query doesn't get the right value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, left-join

My query doesn't give the right output.

I tried with different way such as with CTE as well but nothing help.

I'm trying to write View to display available products with quantity but as some data is not available in StockCloseInventory table it displaying me 0 even though records are available for some products.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
  SOI.InStockPrdID
, SOI.ProdName
, SOI.TradeDrugId
, ISNULL(SOI.Quantity, 0) AS INQTY
, ISNULL(SCI.QuantitySold, 0) AS OUTQTY
, ISNULL(SOI.Quantity, 0) - ISNULL(SCI.QuantitySold, 0) AS AQTY
, SOI.UnitPrice
FROM dbo.StockInventory AS SOI 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.StockCloseInventory AS SCI 
    ON  SOI.InStockPrdID = SCI.InStockPrdID 
    AND SOI.SoldOut <> 1 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.vwTradeDrug AS VTD 
    ON SOI.TradeDrugId = VTD.TradeDrugId
ORDER BY SOI.ProdName
```

And this is the output of my View:
[image]

And here is my Tables

Table: StockInventory
[image]

Table: StockCloseInventory
[image]

vwTradeDrug view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwTradeDrug]
AS
SELECT
  T.TradeDrugId
, T.GenericDrugId
, T.TradeName
, G.GenericProprietaryName
, G.DosageType
, G.Strength
, T.TradeName + ',' + G.GenericProprietaryName + ',' + G.DosageType 
  + ',' + G.Strength AS TradeFullName
FROM dbo.TradeDrug AS T 
  INNER JOIN Inventory.GenericDrug AS G 
    ON T.GenericDrugId = G.GenericId

GO
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question? What's the expected output?

Comment: Sold quantity is not showing up, it is showing as 0 but I got product sold in stockCloseInventory

Comment: `AND coalesce(SOI.SoldOut,0) <> 1`  NULL always evaluates to NULL in Boolean comparisons unless you use the specific is null evaluations; so it's not true and it's not false.  It's Null, which means it is is neither = 1 nor <> 1 thus all the records get excluded from the left join except the one you're excluding(10) :P  or `and ISNULL(SOI.SoldOut,0)` to be consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `SOI.SoldOut <> 1`

First, as Pouya Kamyar pointed out, it is more conventional to include this in a `WHERE` clause than in a `JOIN`.

However, the issue is that the value of this field is mostly `NULL`.

What you want is something more like this:

```
WHERE SOI.SoldOut IS NULL 
   OR SOI.SoldOut <> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I Suggest bring "AND SOI.SoldOut <> 1" in WHERE clause not in join terms

Answer (score 0):

Either change the null data in sold out to be 0 or 1 OR...

handle the nulls so that the boolean compare results in a true or false instead of "NULL" as below.

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
  SOI.InStockPrdID
, SOI.ProdName
, SOI.TradeDrugId
, ISNULL(SOI.Quantity, 0) AS INQTY
, ISNULL(SCI.QuantitySold, 0) AS OUTQTY
, ISNULL(SOI.Quantity, 0) - ISNULL(SCI.QuantitySold, 0) AS AQTY
, SOI.UnitPrice
FROM dbo.StockInventory AS SOI 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.StockCloseInventory AS SCI 
    ON  SOI.InStockPrdID = SCI.InStockPrdID 
    AND ISNULL(SOI.SoldOut,0) <> 1  -- this should do the trick
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.vwTradeDrug AS VTD 
    ON SOI.TradeDrugId = VTD.TradeDrugId
ORDER BY SOI.ProdName
```

Remember Boolean compares on Null values result in NULL (a third value in a Boolean compare!) so SOI.SoldOut <> 1 when SOI.SoldOut is null will result in NULL instead of a true/false you're expecting.

Comment: Your query actually help me to get data of sold quantity but it fails to eliminate the soldOut records, e.g. the InStockPrdID:10 is sold out and in your query its still showing up. but when I tried with @joel brown it works.